# Using variables in for loops bash

Tags: bash

I was just wondering if it is possible to use variables in for loops??
I tried:

```
for number in { eval echo {0..$1}}
do 
    echo 5
done
```

I meant for it to print out 5 the number of times I entered into the prompt however, it acts strangely if I enter in:

```
./test.sh 2
```

It should print out 5 two times, but it prints out 5 four times. Can someone help me with this? And also why is it printing out 4 times instead of 2??

Edit:
For the most part

```
for number in $(seq "$2")
```

Works but If I try a calculation with it, it breaks my code:

```
time=1
total=5
for number in $(seq "$2")
do
    echo "$time + $total" | bc
done
```

Gives:
seq: invalid floating point argument: ‘’
Try 'seq --help' for more information.
Can someone tell me how to fix it??

Comment: Use backtics (`) instead of the outer { } and your loop should work, but start at 1 instead of 0 for your expected two times through the loop.

Comment: If you use `seq "$2"` then you need to provide a numeric 2nd positional parameter when you call the script ex. `./test.sh foo 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It prints out 5 four times because `{ eval echo {0..2}}` results in four whitespace-separated tokens `{`, `0`, `1` and `2}`

If you want to use `$1` as the end of a range expression in bash, it's better to use the external `seq` command:

```
for number in $(seq "$1")
```

or use a C-style `for` loop

```
for ((number=0; number<"$1"; number++))
```

Comment: It works but If I use variables inside of the for loop it breaks immediately

Comment: time=1
total=5
for number in $(seq "$2")
do
    echo "$time + $total" | bc
done

Comment: @YunfeiChen fails how, exactly? How are you calling the script? In particular, how many positional parameters are you supplying (since you apparently changed `$1` to `$2`)

Comment: Gives me:(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: :
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 2: syntax error
(standard_in) 2: illegal character: :
(standard_in) 2: syntax error
(standard_in) 2: syntax error
(standard_in) 2: syntax error

Comment: @YunfeiChen comments are not the right place for follow-on questions - in particular, the formating doesn't allow me to see what you are actually typing. If the "illegal character" is `^M` then that's because your script has Windows line endings.